# Was Miyuki Shirogane's dad simply respecting Kaguya's privacy?

Tags: kaguya-sama-love-is-war

In line with the chess / 9LX references of this series, I find the last part of [S02E10](https://kaguyasama-wa-kokurasetai.fandom.com/wiki/Episode_22) (specifically [Chapter 86](https://kaguyasama-wa-kokurasetai.fandom.com/wiki/Chapter_86)) to be something like a potential checkmate/resign or at least a flag (losing on time, particularly in a winning or drawish position) for Kaguya. I imagine:

> Dad: Well, Miyuki, I caught this girl cheering for you privately and then afterwards Kaguya was talking about how you have 'well-defined' eyes. (In the manga, this is 'beautiful, piercing eyes'.) I also asked if Kaguya has any romantic interest in you, but Kaguya didn't answer.
>
> Miyuki: Oh, is that so, Shinomiya? '[O kawaii yatsume](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/66660/whats-the-difference-between-kaguyas-o-kawaii-koto-and-miyuki-shiroganes).'

([Your move, Shinomiya](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2pEMP.jpg). Now, this isn't necessarily a losing position. But Kaguya is gonna have to come up with a response fast or get flagged.)

**Question**: Anyway, it seems Miyuki's dad doesn't say anything like this (I checked the next few chapters to be sure, but there might've been something later on. IDK). **Is Miyuki's dad, then, simply respecting Kaguya's privacy** or something like in [Bakuman S01E03](https://bakuman.fandom.com/wiki/Episode_3) (or [Chapter 4](https://bakuman.fandom.com/wiki/Chapter_4)) where Miyuki Azuki (Miho Azuki's mom) respects Moritaka Mashiro's privacy? (Maybe Miyuki Shirogane's paternal grandfather did the same for Miyuki Shirogane's mom?) Something like...

> Miyuki: What did you talk about?
>
> Dad: Oh, that's our little secret.

**Or perhaps Miyuki's dad thinks** 'If my son's gonna win love is war, then I don't want it to be because of me. I want the win to be of Miyuki's own accord' ? Something like... [Mr. Shirogane Wants to *Pry*](https://kaguyasama-wa-kokurasetai.fandom.com/wiki/Chapter_86), but Mr. Shirogane doesn't want to *interfere*?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Based on [S03E06](https://kaguyasama-wa-kokurasetai.fandom.com/wiki/Episode_30) (specifically [Chapter 111](https://kaguyasama-wa-kokurasetai.fandom.com/wiki/Chapter_111))

> Yes. Looks like it. Guess I was [overanalysing](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4509/is-it-ok-to-overanalyze-an-anime). Lol.

We see Miyuki's dad

> whisper to Kaguya re Miyuki.

> [image]